# Build an Executable War/Jar with Maven, Tomcat 7 and Websocket

Tags: java, web-services, maven, tomcat, websocket

I'm trying to build an executable WAR/JAR using Maven and Tomcat 7.
The Project contains Websocket and REST API.

In order to do that, I added the following plugin to the pom.xml file:

```
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>tomcat-run</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec-war-only</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <path>/TransSafeGWService</path>
                        <enableNaming>false</enableNaming>
                        <finalName>standalone.jar</finalName>
                        <charset>utf-8</charset>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
```

After that, since REST Service was working but Websocket Service was not, I added other dependencies to the plugin:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>tomcat-run</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec-war-only</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <path>/TransSafeGWService</path>
                        <enableNaming>false</enableNaming>
                        <finalName>standalone.jar</finalName>
                        <charset>utf-8</charset>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat7-websocket</artifactId>
                    <version>7.0.67</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-util</artifactId>
                    <version>7.0.67</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-coyote</artifactId>
                    <version>7.0.67</version>
                </dependency>

            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Using that dependencies, I get this kind of error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.upgrade(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/apache/coyote/http11/upgrade/servlet31/HttpUpgradeHandler;
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.UpgradeUtil.doUpgrade(UpgradeUtil.java:238)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:77)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

In this case what could be the problem?

Below the complete pom.xml file:

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.ti.white</groupId>
<artifactId>TransSafeGWService</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>TransSafeGWService</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.18</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
        <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>



</dependencies>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <webXml>WebContent\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>tomcat-run</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec-war-only</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <path>/TransSafeGWService</path>
                        <enableNaming>false</enableNaming>
                        <finalName>standalone.jar</finalName>
                        <charset>utf-8</charset>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat7-websocket</artifactId>
                    <version>7.0.67</version>
                </dependency>


                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-util</artifactId>
                    <version>7.0.67</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-coyote</artifactId>
                    <version>7.0.67</version>
                </dependency>

            </dependencies>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

As requested, following there is the web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>TransSafeGWService</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Data Acquisition Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.ti.transafe.acquisitionService</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Data Acquisition Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Service/* </url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is probably with the wrong version of servlet api. Tomcat 7 supports 3.0 and below but it seems that you are using servlet version 3.1.

Your exception shows [this method not found](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#upgrade(java.lang.Class)) and this is only part of servlet 3.1 or above.

```
Since: 
 Servlet 3.1
```

Even though you have not included the web.xml in the question, the stacktrace leads to this resolution

Please see your web.xml has this declaration.

```
  <web-app version="3.0"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
```

**Update:**

You are using version 2.1 for [tomcat7-maven-plugin](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.maven/tomcat7-maven-plugin/2.1) which uses tomcat version 7.0.37. And then in the dependencies you are trying to use tomcat jars with a different version 7.0.67. You must use the same version for both.

You have two possibilities:

1. Either set the version of all jars to 7.0.37
2. You can use the latest version [2.2 of tomcat7-maven-plugin](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.maven/tomcat7-maven-plugin/2.2) and use the property for [setting the tomcat version](https://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-trunk/tomcat7-maven-plugin/adjust-embedded-tomcat-version.html). I would
   prefer this one. May be you can set this property with 2.1 also. You can
   try it.

Comment: I added the web.xml description in the previous post. It has already the declaration you wrote.